# Valgrind error when writing struct to file with fwrite - Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)

Tags: c

I have a BankAccount struct that contains an array of transactions. Deposits and withdrawals are stored as +/- ints in this array.

```
struct BankAccount {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int num_of_transactions;
    int transactions[MAX_TRANSACTIONS];
};
```

I am allocating space for the struct on the heap and disposing it when done. I save this struct to file using fwrite.

```
struct BankAccount *new_bank_account(char name[], int initial_deposit) {
    struct BankAccount *acc = malloc(sizeof(struct BankAccount));

    strncpy(acc->name, name, NAME_LENGTH);
    acc->num_of_transactions = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_TRANSACTIONS; i++) {
        acc->transactions[i] = 0;
    }

    if (initial_deposit != 0) {
        make_deposit(acc, initial_deposit);
    }

    return acc;
}

void delete_bank_account(struct BankAccount *acc) {
    free(acc);
}

int save_bank_account(struct BankAccount *acc, char filepath[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "w");
    int res = 0;

    res = fwrite(acc, sizeof(struct BankAccount), 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return res;
}
```

The code works as expected, I am able to make transactions on an account and save it to disk and reload it as well. My test code is below.

```
void test_bank_account_balance() {
    struct BankAccount *acc = new_bank_account("John Doe", 0);
    make_deposit(acc, 50);
    make_deposit(acc, 100);
    make_withdrawal(acc, 50);

    printf("%s has balance = $ %d\n", acc->name, get_balance(acc));

    delete_bank_account(acc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test_save_bank_account();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it through valgrind it gives me errors about uninitialized byte(s). I suspect there is some initialization I am missing in new_bank_account. But I am unable to see what that is.

```
==4311== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==4311==    at 0x411E1D3: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:82)
==4311==    by 0x40B2B04: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1289)
==4311==    by 0x40B29E3: new_do_write (fileops.c:543)
==4311==    by 0x80489B0: test_save_bank_account (p14.c:124)
==4311==    by 0x8048A1D: main (p14.c:140)
==4311==  Address 0x4035032 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4311==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4311==    at 0x402BD14: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==4311==    by 0x80486B5: new_bank_account (p14.c:41)
==4311==    by 0x8048956: test_save_bank_account (p14.c:118)
==4311==    by 0x8048A1D: main (p14.c:140)
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You should be careful with using `strncpy`, as it will not put the terminating `'\0'` in the string if it copies all of `NAME_LENGTH` characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's some padding between the `name` and `num_of_transactions` members of the `struct BankAccount`.

This probably isn't anything to worry about, but if you want to silence valgrind,, using `calloc()` to allocate the memory should work.  Or `memset(acc, 0, sizeof(*acc))`.

Comment: There was another answer, here which also suggested memset, not sure why it is not showing anymore. But I tried that and it still gave the same error. I even did a memset(acc->name, 'a', sizeof(acc->name)); with the same error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ok, so sizeof(*acc) works by zeroing everything, but sizeof(acc->name) doesn't. Further sizeof(acc->name)+sizeof(int) works, Interesting...

Comment: The other answer mentioned doing a `memset()` but only on the `name` member.  That wouldn't have covered initializing the padding between members.